# jsonReader for this JSON schema

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I am trying to get a jQGrid related to a file stored in the server which look similar to this one:

```
    {"newRow":[{
                 "rowId":"r02",
                  "address": [{
                                  "pc":"02020",
                                  "city":"Madrid"
                            ]},
              ]},
     "newCell":[{
                   "rowId":"r02",
                   "cellId":"r02",
                   "outCome":"200"
               ]},
     "newCell":[{
                [{
                   "rowId":"r02",
                   "cellId":"r03",
                   "outCome":"220"
               ]}
               ]},
     "newProvider":[{
                      "cellId":"r03",
                      "name":"Peter"
                   ]},
     "newProvider":[{
                      "cellId":"r03",
                      "name":"Jay"
                   ]},
     }
```

For what I read in some links, it should have another structure but I also read that is possible to modify the jsonReader to adapt it to my structure. But I have no idea of how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `jsonReader`. Here is a linf to the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function).

You should use it as a function. It looks kie that.

```
jsonReader: {
  repeatitems: false,
  id: "Id",
  root: function (obj) { return obj; },
  page: function (obj) { return 1; },
  total: function (obj) { return 1; },
  records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
}
```